# How can I receive a data stream of audio input from an event/device file?

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, microphone, input-devices

Having toyed around with keyboard, mouse, and USB input files for various purposes, I have now come across a situation in which I need to access audio input data in a similar, stream-like method. Is there a specific audio input file to which new microphone data is written? I cannot identify any 'dsp' file, and, based on other posts, believe that this is deprecated(my understanding may be incorrect here, though). Thanks for any help you can offer.